# How to find the particular lan & lng present in the route

Tags: shortest-path

how to find the particular lat and long exist on the route between two position 
direction service in Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one is answered for this question.
And finally i got the solution of my own :D

let me tell you!!
while creating direction service
all the bounds will be stored in "path".
so using this array. draw poly-lines 
then using geometry function "isLocationOnEdge" your_point ,poly-lines array
it will return true or false (that's it :D)
don't forget to add the degree..! default degree is 10e-10 so change it to 10e-2 or something.

```
      var request = {
        origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
        destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }

      // Make the directions request

      directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

          // Box around the overview path of the first route
          var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;


            var my_polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#black',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });

      my_polyline.setMap(map);



  var my_position=new google.maps.LatLng(12.9860932,80.1744085);


  console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(my_position, my_polyline));


      var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
      // alert(boxes.length);


    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });
```